# Magento 1.7: catalog list with attribute size --> slow

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using Magneto 1.7CE to list 16 configurable products on my category view (list.phtml).

you find the following information about the 16 products:

- image, name, price and SIZE

the page generation is very slow (2seconds) with APC, memcache and "use flat catalog" enabled. 
one big "performance eater" is:

```
?php
   $attrs  = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
                    foreach($attrs as $attr) {
                             if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
                                    $options    = $attr['values'];
                    foreach($options as $option) {
                    print "{$option['store_label']} ";
                    }
                }
            }?>
```

do you have any idea, how can I speed up this code? it gives me the "in stock" sizes from every assigned simple product.

if I disable this snipped, the pages generation needs ~0,9 second.

regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

It basically looks like you can replace all of that with this (or something like it) to get just the one attribute.

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Does this code work with configurable products? (I always get the echo "no")

Comment: I see, no it will get the actual products attribute named 'size'.  You will want to check if the product is configurable, then get the child products like so `$children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();`